# My WordPress Plugin Getting Error Revolution Slider, How can i fix it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Revolution Slider Error: You have some jquery.js library include that comes after the revolution files js include.
This includes make eliminates the revolution slider libraries, and make it not work.

To fix it you can:

1. In the Slider Settings -> Troubleshooting set option: Put JS Includes To

Body option to true.

2. Find the double jquery.js include and remove it.

I go to Slider Settings -> Troubleshooting/Problem Handlings but i can't click them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such issues are most often due to plugin conflicts. Try the following:

- Deactivate all of your other plugins and then try to adjust your Rev
  slider settings.
- Ensure you are using the latest WP version.
- Ensure your server is running a PHP version 7 or above.

Comment: I try follow your instructions but t's doesn't work

Comment: You can also try to see if you have the latest Rev slider version. If you have an older version it is most likely not working with the latest WP versions.